# Tic-Tac-Toe JavaScript game problems (interface not responding)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a tic-tac-toe game using HTML, CSS, and JS but the interface is not responding.
Please let me know if I left a typo or should simplify some code. I'm kind of new to this so any input as to how to improve my coding technique or how to implement functions would be appreciated.

CSS:

```
<style>
.row div {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    float: left;
    }
    .row {
     clear: both;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
Click here to play tic tac toe.<br/>
<div>

<div class="row">
<div id="0_0" onclick="place(this)"></div>
<div id="1_0" onclick="place(this)"></div>
<div id="2_0" onclick="place(this)"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div id="0_1" onclick="place(this)"></div>
<div id="1_1" onclick="place(this)"></div>
<div id="2_1" onclick="place(this)"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div id="0_2" onclick="place(this)"></div>
<div id="1_2" onclick="place(this)"></div>
<div id="2_2" onclick="place(this)"></div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
var currentPlayer = "0';
  var won = false;
  function place(box) { 
    if(box.innerText !="" || won) return;
    box.innerText = currentPlayer;
    currentPlayer == "0" ? currentPlayer = "X" : currentPlayer = "0";
    checkGameBoard();
}
function checkGameBoard() {
for(var i = 0; i<= 2; i++) {
checkWinner(document.getElementById(i + "_0").innerText,
document.getElementById(i + "_1").innerText,
document.getElementById(i + "_2").innerText);
checkWinner(document.getElementById("0_" + i).innerText,
document.getElementById("1_" + i).innerText,
document.getElementByID("2_" + i).innerText);
}
checkWinner(document.getElementById("0_0").innerText,
document.getElementById("1_1").innerText,
document.getElementById("2_2").innerText;
checkWinner(document.getElementById("0_2").innerText,
document.getElementById("1_1").innerText,
document.getElementById("2_0").innerText);

}
function checkWinner(first, second, third) {
    if(first != "" && first == second && first == third) {
        alert("Winner!");
        won = true;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, using your browser's dev tools inspect facility can often find errors for you (check the dev tools console). For HTML/CSS syntax errors, running the code past a validator will help clear things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have some typos in here:

```
var currentPlayer = "0';
```

has mismatched quotes

should be:

```
var currentPlayer = "0";
```

```
checkWinner(document.getElementById("0_0").innerText,
document.getElementById("1_1").innerText,
document.getElementById("2_2").innerText;
```

should be:

```
checkWinner(document.getElementById("0_0").innerText,
document.getElementById("1_1").innerText,
document.getElementById("2_2").innerText);
```

missing right parenthesis

`document.getElementByID` should be `document.getElementById`, notice the lower case d in `Id`

here is a working jsFiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/obduj631/2/

I highly recommend working with an IDE such as [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and setting [es-lint](https://eslint.org/) to catch errors such as these.

Comment: Thanks! I was pretty sure I made a type but had a hard time to find it. I'm still getting used to IDEs but for now I prefer working with notepad because of its simplicity lol.